# Creating an object out of Type and adding values to it from xml

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have an object type as below.

```
Type objectType = paramters[0].ParameterType;
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
```

I am trying to create an object of type 'objectType' and I need to populate values to it from xml.
Following is the code snippet which I am trying to do.

```
var fs = new FileStream(WCFServices.XmlFileName, FileMode.Open);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);

var  something = (??)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

how to deserialize into object of type 'objectType'?

Comment: If you have only non-strongly typed version you cannot. You are passing `objectType` to `XmlSerializer` so runtime type of  output instance is proper, but in code you need to work on base `object` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, unless you have a fixed list of types (you could create a generic method that returns the typed instance). Besides, you don't need to, since you don't know what it is (you receive the type in a parameter, so that is 'external knowledge'), it makes no sense casting it to something. The instance has the correct type, so no worry. Just use `object`.

```
object something = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```